# API for querying all cgroups applied to a process in Linux

Tags: linux, cgroups, slurm

I'm working on some software that needs to know its own maximum accessible memory. On Linux, this will depend on the cgroups. From what I have gathered, a process can read from `/proc/self/cgroup` to determine one of the current memory cgroups for itself. However, in reality there is a cgroup hierarchy, and a process is subject to the restrictions of all of its cgroups. How can I determine the minimal available memory across all cgroups applied to the current process?

As an example, when using Slurm, `cat /proc/self/cgroup` returns:

```
[...]
5:memory:/slurm/uid_3119/job_13759394/step_batch/task_0
[...]
```

So one might think that `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/slurm/uid_3119/job_13759394/step_batch/task_0/memory.limit_in_bytes` will show the applicable memory limits. However in this scenario `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/slurm/uid_3119/job_13759394/memory.limit_in_bytes` is the relevant cgroup, because it's more restrictive.
What workflow can be applied to find the tightest memory restrictions in this case?

I note that `systemd` seems to have a lot of cgroup-related utilities, but I want to avoid any external dependencies or assumptions about the system, since my application needs to run on any possible Linux system.

Comment: Are you looking for a `cgroups` v1 or v2 solution?  I believe they are different APIs (i.e. there is no `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` in `cgroupsv2`) and finding a solution that works for any possible Linux system might be tough.

Comment: Ideally both, but at the moment I'm starting with cgroups v1.